# Git installs to a network drive

Tags: bash, git, environment-variables

I'm using Git at work (on Windows 8), but we have a variable in AD called 'HomeDrive', which is annoyingly set to a network drive. Git has decided to install the git bash and other utilities here, which is super annoying. I was wondering if it's possible to go into Git and edit the `$HomeDrive` and `$HomePath` variables as to make Git run off the C drive. Also, apologies if this is the wrong site, but I wasn't sure if it was SO or SU

This is the best I can find on a 'setup' file:

```
@rem Do not use "echo off" to not affect any child calls.

@rem Enable extensions, the `verify other 2>nul` is a trick from the setlocal help
@verify other 2>nul
@setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
@if errorlevel 1 (
    @echo Unable to enable delayed expansion. Immediate expansion will be used.
    @goto fallback
)

@rem Get the absolute path to the parent directory, which is assumed to be the
@rem Git installation root.
@for /F "delims=" %%I in ("%~dp0..") do @set git_install_root=%%~fI
@set PATH=!git_install_root!\bin;!git_install_root!\mingw\bin;!PATH!

@if not exist "!HOME!" @set HOME=!HOMEDRIVE!!HOMEPATH!
#messing about with this does nothing
@if not exist "!HOME!" @set HOME=!USERPROFILE!

@start "gitk" wish.exe "!git_install_root!\bin\gitk" -- %*
@goto end

:fallback
@rem The above script again with immediate expansion, in case delayed expansion
@rem is unavailable.
@for /F "delims=" %%I in ("%~dp0..") do @set git_install_root=%%~fI
@set PATH=%git_install_root%\bin;%git_install_root%\mingw\bin;%PATH%

@if not exist "%HOME%" @set HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
@if not exist "%HOME%" @set HOME=%USERPROFILE%

@start "gitk" wish.exe "%git_install_root%\bin\gitk" -- %*

:end
@rem End of script
```

Comment: sorry man but can you tell me what git are you using(please specify a link) ? did you tested portable ones (if you switch system ) ? thanks

Comment: @MahdiRafatjah I'm using git version 1.9.5 with msysgit 0. It's not portable

Comment: take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606092/why-cant-i-choose-git-install-folder-on-windows) .I also found a portable version in [here](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases) you probebly can find other utilities portable versions too

Comment: That question is unrelated @MahdiRafatjah, and thank you for the portable version but that's an old release, I was looking for a way to make Git Bash use the C:\ drive as it's home drive

Comment: Try adding `set HOMEDRIVE=c:` at the top of the file (or at least before it is used).